# Return a cells value depending on 2 other criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, max

I am looking for the formula that will check that column A:A = "590", then return the sales number in column E:E that is in the same row as the highest test time which is in column K:K

I am currently using  `=IF(O28>0,MAX(IF(FinalTestDataFY24!$A:$A = "590", FinalTestDataFY24!$E:$E)),"")` this is returning the highest sales order number but it is not relating to the highest figure in column K:K

Comment: It would help a lot to help you if you post some sample data and your expected output. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: use the result in a lookup or index/match

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick for me:

> =INDEX(SORTBY(E1:E20,K1:K20,-1),MATCH("590",SORTBY(A1:A20,K1:K20,-1),0))

or

> =LET(sa,SORTBY(A1:K20,K1:K20,-1),INDEX(sa,MATCH("590",DROP(sa,,-10),0),5))

Not really a length-saver formula-wise but it's practice to use different formulas (:
(sorry if I missed a semicolon to comma conversion)

Found another that works:

> =FILTER(E1:E20,K1:K20 = MAXIFS(K1:K20,A1:A20,"590"))

[image]